# AngularJS nested component ui-router not displaying page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on revamping an old AngularJS application including a component based layout. The issue I'm having is that **nesting a component within a component** doesn't seem to work.

Routing:

```
.state('mainApp', {
            url:mapPath(""),
            component: 'main'
        })
        .state('mainApp.project', {
            url: "/project",
            component:'project'
        })
```

Main component HTML:

```
    <div class="all-wrapper solid-bg-all" >
    <div class="layout-w">
        <nav-bar></nav-bar>
        <div class="content-w">
            <top-bar></top-bar>
            <div class="content-i">
                <div class="content-box">
                    <h1>main</h1>
                    <div ui-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using standalone routes for main or project works fine. Main even loads in perfectly on the index on a `ui-view` there. But `main.project` state only displays a blank screen with no errors. The constructor in project is also not being called. When I inspect the page, it just shows the index without main in the first `ui-view`. Any ideas on what is causing this weird problem? Kind of losing my mind since it was working before without components but with controllers.

I've even tried it with `template: '<h1>test</h1>'` and that doesn't seem to work. ES6 doesn't seem to be the problem as well, just converted everything back to plain JS.

**Resolved: error was based on the application**:  Turned out it caught any transition, checked if the user was authenticated and if not sent them to login. However the login state was broken, which resulted in a blank page.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have two ui-view right? So you have smth like index.html with ui-view for main component and this ui-view for project?

Comment: @Kabachok yes. However I just realized a mistake in one of my authentication services. Turned out it caught any transition, checked if the user was authenticated and if not sent them to login. However the login state was broken, which resulted in a blank page. Thanks for replying anyway ;)

Comment: glad it ended well :)